# Issues after installing Cinnamon on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, cinnamon

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and tries to install Cinnamon on this. But after the installation I am facing various issues.

1. Mouse is not working on Login screen.
2. Menu is showing as deselected (dim) for most of the applications including Google Chrome and sublime. I am not able to select the menu items like Open etc.
3. Sometimes, when I turn on the laptop, it is going to Low Graphics Mode.
4. If I connect to another monitor, it is not detecting it automatically. Before it was doing it.
5. If I take settings or something, it is showing broken graphics.

I am attaching the screenshots for the Details screen.

By the way I have removed all Cinnamon things from my system. But it is not fixing the issue.

Thanks for any help.

[image: Details Screen]

[image: Mouse and Touch pad settings screen]

Answer (score 0):

If you went straight to installing cinnamon without adding repository, chances are; you installed cinnamon for previous Ubuntu versions mostly 12.04/10. Run the following commands.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinnamon

This will reinstall cinnamon stable version and am sure it will fix everything, then restart for effects to take place.
If you still experience problems, run the following commands

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cinnamon

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update -f

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: I have tried this. But it is not fixing the issue. Now also everything is same like before.

Comment: I have added another screenshot of the mouse and Touch Pad settings.

Comment: i cant see the new screenshot, where is it?

Comment: can you please refresh and check ?